# Assign a variable to a LINQ result

Tags: c#, linq, variables, variable-assignment

I am getting the following error
"The left-hand side of an assingnment must be a variable, property or indexer"
in this code:

```
class SomeClass{
string SomeString {get; set;}
}

ObservableCollection<SomeClass> someCollection;

void foo(SomeClass foo2, string y){

someCollection.First(x => x.SomeString == y) = foo2;

}
```

I understood why this error was happening and i wrote this code to solve it:

```
class SomeClass{
string SomeString {get; set;}
}

ObservableCollection<SomeClass> someCollection;

void foo(SomeClass foo2, string y){

someCollection[someCollection.IndexOf(someCollection.First(x => x.SomeString == y))] = foo2;

}
```

But it doesn't seem an elegant way to do it.
is there a correct way to do it?

Comment: The title should be: Replace an item in an ObservableCollection because that's what you try to achieve in an "elegant way".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating some extension methods to extend `ObservableCollection` for your new capability:

```
public static class ObservableCollectionExt {
    public static int IndexOf<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> aCollection, Func<T, bool> predFn) => aCollection.Select((c, n) => new { c, n }).FirstOrDefault(cn => predFn(cn.c))?.n ?? -1;
    public static void SetFirstItem<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> aCollection, Func<T, bool> predFn, T newItem) {
        var index = aCollection.IndexOf(predFn);
        if (index != -1)
            aCollection[index] = newItem;
    }
}
```

Then you can use them in `foo`:

```
void foo(SomeClass foo2, string y) {
    someCollection.SetFirstItem(x => x.SomeString == y, foo2);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The left hand side is still not a variable.

```
class SomeClass{
string SomeString {get; set;}
}

ObservableCollection<SomeClass> someCollection;

void foo(string y){

var foo2 = someCollection[someCollection.IndexOf(someCollection.First(x => x.SomeString == y))] ;

}
```

Comment: `someCollection[...]` is certainly a modifiable lvalue.